# searching in map through find function for key value is not happening properly

Tags: c++, stl, linked-list

In the code below, I am performing search in map through key value but am not able to get the desired results though common elements are present in both lists and find with map should give expected output. 
Is there any issues while performing find with map? is that right approach ?

input

list1:10->15->4->20
list2:10->2->4->8

expected output:
common->data=4
common->data=10

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <map>
    using namespace std;
    struct node
    {
        int data;
        struct node* next;
    };
    /* A utility function to insert a node at the beginning of 
       a linked list*/
    void push(struct node** head_ref, int new_data);
    /* A utility function to insert a node at the begining of a linked list*/
    void push (struct node** head_ref, int new_data)
    {
        /* allocate node */
        struct node* new_node =
            (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        /* put in the data */
        new_node->data = new_data;
        /* link the old list off the new node */
        new_node->next = (*head_ref);
        /* move the head to point to the new node */
        (*head_ref) = new_node;
    }
     /*insert the head1 into map and find the head2 in map*/
    int create_hash(struct node* head1,struct node* head2)
    {
      int flag=0;
     map<node*,bool> intersect;

    while(head1!=NULL)
    {
    printf("first_list->data=%d\n",head1->data);
    intersect[head1]=true;
    head1=head1->next;
    }
    while(head2!=NULL)
    {
    printf("second_list->data=%d\n",head2->data);
    if (intersect.find(head2)!= intersect.end())
           printf("common->data=%d\n",head2->data); 
           flag=1;
           head2=head2->next;
    }
    if(flag==1)
    {
    return 0;
    }
    return -1;
    }
    /* Drier program to test above function*/
    int main()
    {
        /* Start with the empty list */
        struct node* head1 = NULL;
        struct node* head2 = NULL;
        int ret_val;
        struct node* unin = NULL;
        /*create a linked lits 10->15->4->20 */
        push (&head1, 20);
        push (&head1, 4);
        push (&head1, 15);
        push (&head1, 10);
        /*create a linked list 10->2->4->8 */
        push (&head2, 10);
        push (&head2, 2);
        push (&head2, 4);
        push (&head2, 8);
        ret_val = create_hash (head1, head2);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: this is a mixture between a C code and little C++. this is the main problem

Answer (score 1):

You populate the `intersect` map with *pointers to nodes* in the first list, and then search that map for pointers to nodes in the second list.  Since nodes are not shared between lists, the search will never succeed.

In the context of this implementation, the map should contain the data values, not node pointers.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there anyway if node based searching can be performed  by modifying the current shared code.

Comment: map<int,bool> intersect; will solve my problem but How to solve the same by map<node*,bool> ?

Comment: Instead of `intersect.find(head2)` you could use `std::find_if(intersect.begin(), intersect.end(), [head2](node* n){return n->data == head2->data;})`. (If you can't use a C++11 lambda, there are equivalent but more verbose constructs).

Comment: I am trying to compile the same with -std=c++0x option but still getting compilation error.